# Estimation of $\lvert f' \rvert$ via Cauchy-integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, inequality, cauchy-integral-formula

I am asked to prove that if $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is entire and $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq 1$ on $\overline{B_1(0)}$, then $\lvert f'(z) \rvert \leq 4$ on $\overline{B_\frac{1}{2}(0)}$.

What I did is to choose any $z \in \overline{B_\frac{1}{2}(0)}$. I then easily observed that $\overline{B_\frac{1}{2}(z)} \subseteq \overline{B_1(0)}$. Then:
$$
\lvert f'(z) \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial K_\frac{1}{2}(z)} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2}~\mathrm{d}w\right \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_{\partial K_\frac{1}{2}(z)} \frac{\overbrace{\lvert f(w) \rvert}^{\leq 1}}{\underbrace{\lvert w-z\rvert^2}_{=\frac{1}{4}}}~\mathrm{d}w \leq 2
$$
So I got an even better estimate... . Do you know if I made a mistake? Thank you.

I am also personally interested in what is the sharpest estimation of this kind. I know that $\lvert f' \rvert = 1$ is possible e.g. for $f(z) = z^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bound seems alright, but there is a better bound by using the [Schwarz-Pick thereom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). Assume that $f(z)$ is non-constant, so $|f(z)|=1$ does not occur in the interior of $|z|\leq 1.$ Using that and applying to holomorphic mapping $f(z)$ from unit disk to unit disk, one gets that $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq \frac 1{1-|z|^2},$$ for $|z|<1$, which implies that $|f'(z)|\leq \frac 1{1-|z|^2}.$ With $|z|\leq \frac 1 2,$ this shows that $|f'(z)|\leq \frac 4 3.$ The bound is sharp as can be seen from the example $$f(z)=\frac {2z-1}{z-2}=\frac{z-\frac 1 2}{\frac 1 2z-1},$$ which maps unit disk to itself with $|f'(\frac 1 2)|=\frac 4 3.$

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you!

Comment: But I have one additional question: Your function $f$ is of course not defined on the entire plane $\mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to find some $f$ that is defined on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Ah, I see, so technically your question is not answered completely (so far). I will think about it. Feel free to accept a better answer.

Comment: Thank you. Answer ist great, don't worry